# how to properly use Models on Spring 4?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new using Spring's MVC (but Ive been using it for some years at other php frameworks).

I have many doubts, I read the spring info and seems to be right and all.. then Ichecked this tutorial http://javahash.com/spring-4-mvc-hello-world-tutorial-full-example/ and it works and all, but on the controller part, there is a code I dont understand, and Id like to know how to properly use the Models on Spring.

As far as I know, the models should call make the calls to the db, so, what about the services (interfaces and implementations) and the DTOs?

At the example they make something like this:

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController { 

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String hello(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "helloworld";
    }

}
```

It receives a model as parameter... I bet if there is any, Spring would use a default one, what if I want to add more interaction and lets say, specifiy a model to call the db? Any idea how I could do that?

And if I want to add a service... I am a little bit clueless about it, if someone could help me to understand...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model is a map representing the data that the view needs. It can contain one or more entities, or simple objects, or strings, or whatever you want.

MVC doesn't require the use of a database. The model does not "call the db". You can inject a repository into your controller to load data from a db into your model.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public class FooController {

  @Autowired
  private FooRepository fooRepository;

  @RequestMapping
  String getFoos(Model model) {

    List<Foo> foos = fooRepository.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("foos", foos);

    model.addAttribute("someOtherDataYourViewNeeds", "bar");

    return "foo/list";

  }

}
```

Comment: so, what does basically a model do? can I have a model file with some stuff? or is just a "virtual" part of the mvc?

Comment: @jpganz18 model is a container for the data for a view. Spring also does two-way data binding, which you should read up on

Answer (score 1):

This Model Object is injected by spring, and his content will be sent to the view.
You can see the documentation for Model interface here http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/.
If you wanna access some object on your view, you can you use
`model.addAttribute(object)`.
I think you could read [The IoC Container](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) documentation to understand how spring works.